# How to get best estimator parameters using AdaBoost and GridSearchCV

Tags: python, adaboost, gridsearchcv

I'm using `AdaBoost` and I'd like to see which estimator parameters work best using `GridSearchCV`. Is it possible to include the estimator parameters in my 'parameters' variable? For instance, how can I vary the max_depth for the DecisionTreeClassifier?

```
pipe = Pipeline([
             ('normalize', MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))),
             ('scale', StandardScaler()),
             ('booster', AdaBoostClassifier()),
             ])

parameters = {
        "booster__base_estimator": [DecisionTreeClassifier(), RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20)],
        "booster__n_estimators": [20, 30, 40],
        "booster__learning_rate": [0.1, 0.5, 1]
     }
```

Comment: Try `booster__base_estimator__max_depth`?

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr that was much easier than I expected. However, what if I want to use a parameter that DecisionTreeClassifier has and RandomForestClassifier doesn't have?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to use a param that's available in one estimator but missing in the other. I also haven't found a simple solution to tinkering the params for only one estimator and not the other. So far, I've resorted to building 2 pipelines with their own estimators and comparing their results.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use GridSearchCV for AdaBoost with base estimator as DecisionTree claassifier. Then hyperparameters of the base estimator should be denoted using double underscore.

```
paramgrid = {'base_estimator__min_samples_split':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
         'base_estimator__min_samples_leaf':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
         'base_estimator__max_depth':[2,3,4,5,6,7],'n_estimators': [100,200,300,400,500],'learning_rate':[0.01,0.1]}

R=GridSearchCV(AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier()),paramgrid,cv = 5,verbose=3,scoring='f1',n_jobs=-1)

R.fit(X_train,y_train)

R.best_estimator_
```